# Find the difference between two vectors and the mean of the result

Tags: r

So, with the help of someone here in stats i could solve  most of my problems.

Now i'm stuck at this part:

I have the below code, which worked very well if this values were fixed.

```
immediate.amput.below.EV
watchful.wait.EV
```

Now what they are is vectors. They represent a vector with [n_psa] size.
What i need to do is, i need iterate for n_psa values, i.e for 100 values and find the difference between each  immediate.amput.below.EV[1] - watchful.wait.EV[1] and so on, save the results only as positive numbers, even if the output is a negative number in a new vector, and find the mean of the new vector.

This is what i used to do.

```
DELTA_COST <- max(immediate.amput.below.EV,watchful.wait.EV) - min(immediate.amput.below.EV,watchful.wait.EV)
mean(DELTA_COST)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the absolute value in R, use the function `abs()`. Below is an example for vectors a and b. The sizes can change as long as they have the same dimension, otherwise you will get strange results or errors.

```
a <- c(1, 4, 8, 20)
b <- c(50, 2, 4, 21)
DELTA_COST <- abs(a-b)

DELTA_COST
[1] 49   2   4  1

mean(DELTA_COST)
[1] 14
```